# how to parse master edition account in anchor? (MasterEditionV2)

Tags: anchor, metaplex, master-edition

im define in account context but give me error

```
#[account(mut)]
pub master_edition : Account<'info, mpl_token_metadata::state::MasterEditionV2>,
```

but it show error lint like this :

```
the trait bound `mpl_token_metadata::state::MasterEditionV2: anchor_lang::AccountSerialize` is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait `anchor_lang::AccountSerialize`:
```

so im try to unpack manually with :

```
    let master_edition = MasterEditionV2::from_account_info(
        &ctx.accounts.master_edition.to_account_info()
    );
    match master_edition {
        Ok(data) => {
            msg!("[master_edition] owner {:?}", ctx.accounts.master_edition.owner);
            msg!("[master_edition] key {:?}", ctx.accounts.master_edition.key);
            msg!("[master_edition] [unpack] max_supply {:?}", data.max_supply);
            msg!("[master_edition] [unpack] supply {:?}", data.supply);
            msg!("[master_edition] [unpack] key {:?}", data.key);
        },
        Err(err) => {
            msg!("[master_edition] error {:?}", err);
        }
    }
```

but give me error when transaction running :

```
[master_edition] error Custom(63)
```

what i miss something? thanks for alll help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Anchor 0.27 release just added deserialization for the `MasterEditionAccount` account. You can find more information about it in the [changelog](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and the corresponding [pull request](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/pull/2393).

> Include MasterEditionAccount to spl metadata to deserialize master
> edition v2 accounts

```
pub struct CreateDrop<'info> {
    /// authority over and payer for the drop
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
        seeds = [state::PREFIX.as_bytes(), Metadata::id().as_ref(), metadata_mint.key().as_ref(), state::EDITION.as_bytes()],
        seeds::program = Metadata::id(),
        bump,
    )]

    #[account(constraint = master_edition.supply > 0)]
    pub master_edition: Account<'info, MasterEditionAccount>,
    
    ...
}
```

You may need to add the `metadata` feature to the `anchor-spl` dependency in `Cargo.toml`.

```
[dependencies]
anchor-spl = {version = "0.27.0",features = ["metadata"]}
```

Once enabled, you should be able to access the content using:

```
use anchor_spl::metadata::{...}
```

The Account types supported by `Account<'info, T>` are specific to Anchor, which is why trying to add the account type directly from `mpl_token_metadata` won't work.

```
#[account(mut)]
pub master_edition : Account<'info, mpl_token_metadata::state::MasterEditionV2>,
```

https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/accounts/account/struct.Account.html#

Comment: thanks for your help, actually this turned out to be due to a personal problem where I misunderstood what a master edition was, instead I gave the mint address of the master edition.

thanks for the help, previously I was using version 0.26.0, and thanks to you I finally upgraded to 0.27.0
and find directly class deserialize for MasterEditionAccount. thanks a lot for the help once again.